# Route Binding in Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, routes, lumen

I want to implement route binding in Lumen and achieve

controller class

```
public function summary(Request $request, App $app){
   dd($app->name);
}
```

custom RouteServiceProvider

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use mmghv\LumenRouteBinding\RouteBindingServiceProvider as BaseServiceProvider;


class RouteServiceProvider extends BaseServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Boot the service provider
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $binder = $this->binder;
        $binder->bind('appId', 'App\Models\App', function ($e){
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'App Not found'
            ], 404);
        });
    }
}
```

and added in app

```
$app->register(App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class);
```

I have debugged my code is going to RouteServiceProvider but when i dump in controller its always null. I am not sure how to achieve that.

Comment: well `app` isn't `appId` ... but what is `null`?  does Lumen even have Route Model Binding?

Comment: @lagbox Thanks, After spending 5 hours I noticed `appId` and `app`, Its fixed now.